# Getting changed values from combobox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, combobox

quick question, let's say I have a combobox in a windows form, that get's filled with data from a sql table, and when a value is selected, it fills, let's say a textbox or a label with data from the same row. What I need (and can't get to make it work properly) is that each time I select a different value on the combobox, it will reflect those changes on the hypothetical textbox or label, without pressing any extra control, just by changing values on the combobox. For example:

Let's say I have this data on an SQL column and it's showing on a combobox on a windows form:

> 1. London
> 2. New York
> 3. Paris
> 4. etc.

and each time I select one city from the combobox, I want get that data from sql and show those changes on a textbox that has the data of the zip code, country, etc of each city.
What I'm currently using is the SelectedValue property that works fine th first time you select an item but doesn't change the data on the other controls when you select another value the second time.

Do you have any idea on how to implement this or a better way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to take a look at the [SelectedIndexChangedEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That's what I wanted! Thank you so much man!